# winston timer not printing time

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am running this example given in winston timer documentation -

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'silly',
  format: winston.format.simple(),
});

logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.simple(),
}));

require('winston-timer')(logger, {"useColors":false});
logger.start_log('something', 'silly');
logger.stop_log('something', 'silly');
```

and in the output I am supposed to see the time, but I am seeing this instead -

```
nodejstutorials % node winstontimerbasic.js
silly: Starting timer "something"
silly: Finished timer "something" in
```

I don't see the elapsed time in the output. I am not sure what am I missing while going through the documentation. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use timestamp option you should say that when you're creating winston instance.

Change your winston import with this:

```
const winston, { format } = require('winston');
```

Destructure required properties from format:

```
const { combine, timestamp, printf } = format;
```

Create custom print option when you're creating your winston instance:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: "error",
    format: combine(
        format.errors({ stack: true }), // log the full stack
        timestamp(), // get the time stamp part of the full log message
        printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack }) => {
            // formating the log outcome to show/store
            return `${level === "error" ? "❌" : "✅"} ${level}: ${message} ${
                level === "error" ? "|  " + timestamp.substring(0, 19) : ""
            }   ${"\n"} ${level === "error" ? stack : ""}`;
        }),
        format.metadata() // >>>> ADD THIS LINE TO STORE the ERR OBJECT IN META field
    ),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({ level: "info" }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: "logs.log", level: "info" }),
    ],
});
```

This will create a custom printf option for your winston logger. You can export it and you it like:

```
logger.error(error)
logger.info("this is an info")
```

And of course you can custumize printf option accordion to your taste

Comment: I don't want the timestamp, I want to measure time elapsed. As per their documentation, the above code should print time elapsed between start_log and stop_log calls, but I am seeing a blank instead.

Comment: I thought you re looking for timestamp. I've not used print time elapsed before. Sorry for the misunderstanding